# Return after try/catch block on template function

Tags: c++, templates, exception, return, try-catch

I am running into an issue here because the return of `stack.front()` isn't pointing to anything when the stack is empty. So despite catching the exception, I end up getting bad access run-time errors.

Is there a better way to go about doing this? I want the program to continue functioning, even when certain functions are called and have errors.

Comment: Why are you catching the exception in the function?  You should propagate it out to the caller so they can handle what to do when popping and empty stack.

Comment: You need to catch it somewhere and this somewhere is a function that uses your StackList. Call top() inside a try block. You know it can throw.

Comment: You should check whether your stack is empty before calling top(). This is the most correct way of dealing with an empty stack issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into issues because you immediately catch exception after throwing it. The exception doesn't get out of `top()` and you're calling `getFront()` on an empty stack. Rethrow your exception in the catch block or don't catch it all.